# Replacing traditional newForLoop with Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, java-8, java-stream

So, finally making a relatively large jump from Java 6 to Java 8, I've read up a fair amount of Java 8 Streams API. Unfortunately, almost all the examples that have been asked are almost close to what I'm trying to figure out how to do, but not close enough.

What I have is

```
final List<Function<? super Double, Double>> myList = generateList();
final double myVal = calculate(10);

private double calculate(double val) {
    for (Function<? super Double, Double> function : this.myList) {
        val += function.apply(val);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Now, I've come to understand I could do something similar with `.stream().forEach()`, but that only applies the foreach and streams require final variables. I've tried to explore a bit with `DoubleStream` to get a `sum()`, but I'd need to re-apply the current sum to each `Function` and add that sum to the next function, as the code example above shows.

Is this possible with pure Stream API?

Edit: So after testing with the `reduce()` area, I ran a simple test on the time it takes to perform this type of calculation and the results aren't in favor of streams. Here's an example https://gist.github.com/gabizou/33f616c08bde5ab97e56. Included are the log outputs from the fairly basic test.

Comment: No, not really.  The `Stream` operations don't really work for inherently sequential operations like what you're doing.

Comment: I understand that, I was just hoping that streams would have the same performance in the end. In the grand scheme of things, quite possibly for large sets of functions, this might end up in parity, but for what I'm doing, it's not likely. Of course, as we progress with new Java versions, we might see optimizations and enhancements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the stream API to compose a function out of your list of functions.

```
static List<Function<? super Double, Double>> myList
    = Arrays.asList(d -> d + 4, d -> d * 2, d -> d - 3);

static Function<Double, Double> total=myList.stream()
    .map(f -> (Function<Double, Double>) d -> d + f.apply(d))
    .reduce(Function::andThen).orElse(Function.identity());

static double calculate(double val) {
    return total.apply(val);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(calculate(10));
}
```

The stream operation which produces the composed function does not have the associativity problem and could in theory even run in parallel (though there is no benefit here) while the result is a single function which is per se sequential and never dissolved into parts which would need to be associative.

Comment: Just a note: parallelizing this is not just "no benefit", it's *horrible*. In sequential mode, it runs well even for 1000 functions. Using the parallel stream... even with 10 functions it seems to get deadlocked or something.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: that deadlock seems to be caused by running in the `static` initializer of the class. When I move the code into a method, in runs without problems. I’ll investigate that issue as it seems to be a serious bug.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: the problem is that lambda expressions produce new classes which call synthetic methods back on their defining class. Asynchronous method invocations, performed on a class which is not fully initialized, will wait for the completion of the initialization, thus if the initializer itself waits for the completion of that asynchronous operation, you have a dead-lock. Therefore, parallel stream operations in a `static` initializer are a no-go.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This should probably be written in bold somewhere. Maybe you should create a question with a self-answer about it.

Comment: What is this doing exactly? I just ran it and it returned 141 (using the values in the code) when I expected it to be 41 ( [10 +4] + [10*2] + [10 -3])

Comment: @Leonardo Pina: Composing is not like `f(x)+g(x)+h(x)`, it’s like `h(g(f(x)))`, i.e. the output of one function is the input to the next one. In this special case, each function `f` is projected to `x+f(x)`, hence, the resulting function is like `h(g(f(x)+x)+f(x)+x)+g(f(x)+x)+f(x)+x`. This is what the question’s loop is doing too; it’s adding the function’s result to `val`, but `val` is the argument to the next function.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use a stream solution, by performing a *reduction*:

```
private double calculate(double val) {
    return myList.stream().reduce(val, (d, f) -> d + f.apply(d), (a, b) -> a + b);
}
```

A reduction takes each element and aggregates (reduces) it to one value. There are 3 flavours of the `reduce()` method - the one used here does the trick.

---

Some test code:

```
static Function<? super Double, Double> a = (d) -> d + 4;
static Function<? super Double, Double> b = (d) -> d * 2;
static Function<? super Double, Double> c = (d) -> d - 3;
static List<Function<? super Double, Double>> myList = Arrays.asList(a, b, c);

static double calculate(double val) {
    return myList.stream().reduce(val, (d, f) -> d + f.apply(d), (a, b) -> a + b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(calculate(10));
}
```

Output:

```
141.0
```

Comment: I don't think it does the same thing. The original, for three functions f,g,h would give you f(val) + g(f(val)) + h(f(val) + g(f(val))), whereas that reducer allows combining partial results with `+`, thus you could end up with f(val) + g(val) + h(val) or something similar. The combiner here does not meet the constraints in the docs.

Comment: I just tested logically, that's what the code indeed does.

    10 + (10 + 4) = 24 THEN
    24 + (24 *2) = 72 THEN
    72 + (72 - 3) = 141

The end result is still the same. Now i'm genuinely curious about the performance costs of using streams in this case versus the traditional methods.

Comment: @gab my guess on performance would be traditional would be faster, but coworkers will be more impressed with the stream version - something to consider :)

Comment: I did run a very quick and dirty test using the code example from this answer, and sadly, it's just performing miserably. My guess is that it's requiring a lot of overhead than it needs (something that compilers may be able to optimize sooner or later). Unless I'm doing something completely wrong in the code example (edited at the end).

Comment: Actually this is work for (hopefully) upcoming [`foldLeft`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133680). Here the operation is non-associative, so reduce would simply produce incorrect result in parallel.

Comment: @RealSkeptic The final *combiner* reduction parameter is never invoked on a non-parallel stream (as for a `List`). It's a wonder they don't have a 2-parameter version with a default "exploding" combiner - I could put anything in there and it would have no effect (except for `null`, which sadly causes a NPE even though it's never called).

Comment: That's just it, isn't it? The fact that the combiner is never called is undocumented, and is an *implementation detail* that should *not* be relied upon, It's quite intentional, and any use that doesn't produce the same results for parallel and non-parallel versions of the same stream should be avoided.

Comment: If code relies on the combiner never been called, the minimum it should do is to provide `(x,y)->{throw new AssertionError();}` as combiner instead of something that silently produces wrong values. @gabizou: your performance test lacks any warmup phase so you are measuring the class loading and initialization time of the stream framework.

Answer (score 0):

This particular example is very problematic for the Java 8 streams. They are designed for operations in which the order is not important.

Function application is not associative. To explain, let's take a simpler example, in which one wants to take a number and divide it by a list of numbers:

```
static List<Double> dividers = Arrays.asList( 3.5, 7.0, 0.5, 19.0 );

public double divideByList( double a ) {
    for ( Double d : dividers ) {
        a /= d;
    }
    return a;
}
```

So, what you get is

```
a ÷ 3.5 ÷ 7.0 ÷ 0.5 ÷ 19.0
```

The arithmetic is simple - division is left-associative, meeaning that this is equivalent to

```
a ÷ ( 3.5 × 7.0 × 0.5 × 19.0)
```

**not**

```
a ÷ ( 3.5 ÷ 7.0 ÷ 0.5 ÷ 19.0 )
```

and **not**

```
( a ÷ 3.5 ÷ 7.0 ) ÷ ( 0.5 ÷ 19.0 )
```

The stream operations, those that are based on reduce/collectors, require that the "reducing" operation will be left-associative. This is because they want to allow the operation to be parallelized, such that some threads will do some of the operations, and then the result could be combined. Now, if your our operator was multiplication rather than division, this would not be a problem, because

```
a × 3.5 × 7.0 × 0.5 × 19.0
```

is the same as

```
(a × 3.5 × 7.0 ) × (0.5 × 19)
```

which means one thread could do the `a × 3.5 × 7.0`, and another could do the `0.5 × 19.0` operation, and then you could multiply the result and get the same thing as in the sequential calculation. But for division, that doesn't work.

Function application is also non-associative, just like division. That is, if you have functions `f`,`g` and `h`, and you run your sequential calculation, you'll end up with:

```
result = val + f(val) + g(val + f(val)) + h(val + f(val) + g(val + f(val)))
```

Now, if you have two intermediate threads, one applying `f` and `g`, the other one applying `h`, and you want to combine the result - there is no way to get the correct values into the `h` in the first place.

---

You may be tempted to try this with a method like `Stream.reduce`, as @Bohemian suggested. But the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) warns you against this:

> ```
> <U> U reduce(U identity,
>              BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator,
>              BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The identity value must be an identity for the combiner function. This means that for all u, combiner(identity, u) is equal to u. Additionally, the combiner function must be compatible with the accumulator function; for all u and t, the following must hold:
>
> ```
> combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t)) == accumulator.apply(u, t)
> ```

For an operation like `+`, the identity is 0. For `*`, the identity is 1. So it is against the documentation to use your `val` as the `identity`. And the second condition is even more problematic.

Although **the current implementation** for a non-parallel stream does not use the *combiner* part, which makes both the conditions unneeded, this is **not documented**, and a future implementation, or a different JRE's implementation, may decide to create intermediate results and use the *combiner* to join them, perhaps to improve performance or for any other consideration.

So, despite the temptation, one should *not* use `Stream.reduce` to try to imitate the original sequential processing.

---

There *is* a way to do it, that doesn't actually break the documentation. It involves keeping a mutable object that holds the result (it has to be an object so that it's effectively final while still mutable), and using the [`Stream.forEachOrdered`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-), which guarantees that the operations will be performed in the order they appear in the stream, if the stream is ordered. And a list's stream has a defined order. This works even when you use `myList.stream().parallel()`.

```
public static double streamedCalculate(double val) {
    class MutableDouble {
        double currVal;
        MutableDouble(double initVal) {
            currVal = initVal;
        }
    }

    final MutableDouble accumulator = new MutableDouble(val);

    myList.stream().forEachOrdered((x) -> accumulator.currVal += x.apply(accumulator.currVal));
    return accumulator.currVal;
}
```

Personally, I find that your original loop is more readable than this, so there is really no advantage to using streams here.

Based on a comment by @Tagir Valeev, there is a [foldLeft](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133680) operation planned for future Java versions. It may look more elegant when that happens.