# How to apply a list of functions to a value in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

Let's say I have this imperative code:

```
    List<Function<T, T>> functions = ...
    T value = ...
    for (Function<T, T> function : functions) {
        value = function.apply(value);
    }
```

How do I write this in the functional style (like what fold does in Scala)?

Comment: you could box the value and `#forEach` the `functions` list, but that's not really gaining you anything (and isn't _truly_ functional anyhow). Overall the code looks fine for what it is, java is an imperative language.

Comment: [Working with an ArrayList of Functions in Java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274124/working-with-an-arraylist-of-functions-in-java-8) This will help

Comment: Looks close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32338553/2711488)…

Comment: The problem with foreach is, they need to update a shared state. What I need is passing the result of one function to the next one in the chain.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This has just been asked a few hours ago for a `Consumer`... You could reduce them to a single function and apply that:

```
@SafeVarargs
private static <T> Function<T, T> combineF(Function<T, T>... funcs) {
    return Arrays.stream(funcs).reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen);
}
```

Comment: While semantically the same, `.reduce(Function::andThen).orElse(Function.identity())` may produce a slightly more efficient function.

Comment: @Holder Are there any issues with using `.reduce(Function::andThen).orElseGet(Function::identity)`, instead?

Comment: @srborlongan that has been discussed before, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261253/when-i-need-to-use-optional-orelseget-over-optional-orelse/44261755#44261755

Comment: Well, `reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen)` will use the identity function as starting point and call `andThen` for each function producing a combined function of the identity function and the next function (unless the identity overrides `andThen`, which it doesn’t in the current JRE). In contrast, `reduce(Function::andThen)` will return the sole function of a single element stream and only call `andThen`, if there are more than one function and using the `identity()` only if the stream is empty.

Comment: @srborlongan: there is no issue with it, but also no saving as the creation of the `Supplier` is not cheaper than calling `Function.identity()`. If this happens multiple times at different places in your code, the net outcome will be that `orElse(Function.identity())` will be cheaper than `orElseGet(Function::identity)`. See also […Function.identity() or t->t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041480/2711488)

Comment: @Holger the JVM is likely to optimize this out automatically anyway, isn't it?

Comment: @Didier L: which one are you referring to? Temporary instances like `Function::identity` passed to `orElseGet(…)` are likely to be eliminated. When composing `Function.identity()` with other functions, the JVM may inline their code path (though it may hit the thresholds if you have multiple functions), when being evaluated, so the CPU performance may be the same, but the higher memory consumption of the composed function is likely to stay as long as the function is referenced…

Comment: Thanks guys for the answer and the discussion around these 2 different options.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant on Eugene's answer, *just for fun*:

```
public static <T> Function<T, T> combine(List<Function<T, T>> functions) {
    return new Object() {
        Function<List<Function<T, T>>, Function<T, T>> combiner = list ->
            list.size() == 1 ? list.get(0) :
            list.get(0).andThen(this.combiner.apply(list.subList(1, list.size())));
    }.combiner.apply(functions);
}
```

This creates an anonymous inner class with an attribute that is a recursive lambda. This attribute is named `combiner` and it's a *higher-order function* that takes a list of functions as an argument and returns a function as a result. This higher-order function returns the first function of the list if the list contains only one element, or applies `andThen` to the first function of the list, with the function that results of the recursive call to the higher-order function with the sublist of functions that starts with the second element.

The anonymous inner class is needed because recursive lambdas can only be defined as attributes of a class.

Needless to say this is way more complex than streaming the list and reducing with the `Function::andThen` binary operator. Besides, recursive lambdas aren't for free: they use the stack for the recursive calls.

Comment: Aside from creating fields for the lambdas to recurse upon, another (less intuitive) way in Java 8 is to use a [Y combinator](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#Java).

Comment: @srborlongan Or [trampolines](http://raganwald.com/2013/03/28/trampolines-in-javascript.html)...

Comment: after 5 years, I wrote a combinator, in our code base, with your help. God, I miss the years when I had time for fun coding. thank you Federico.

Comment: Hi @Eugene! 5 years from this answer and I find it soooo convoluted!