# Applying functions of various types to a value

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming, bounded-wildcard

Let's say I have a method that **applies multiple functions to a value**.

Example usage:

```java
String value = "a string with numb3r5";
Function<String, List<String>> fn1 = ...
Function<List<String>, String> fn2 = ...
Function<String, List<Integer>> fn3 = ...

InputConverter<String> converter = new InputConverter<>(value);
List<Integer> ints = converter.convertBy(fn1, fn2, fn3);
```

Is it possible to make it apply multiple functions with **various inputs and return values**?

I've tried using wildcards, but this doesn't work.

```java
public class InputConverter<T> {
    private final T src;

    public InputConverter(T src) {
        this.src = src;
    }

    public <R> R convertBy(Function<?, ?>... functions) {
        R value = (R) src;

        for (Function<?, ?> function : functions)
            value = (R) function.apply(value);
                                       ^^^^^
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Stream`, or `Optional`. Or take inspiration from their design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a chain on `Function` like the following

```java
Function<String, List<Integer>> functionChain = fn1.andThen(fn2).andThen(fn3);
```

You can achieve nearly the same thing by using raw types

```java
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
public <R> R convertBy(Function... functions) {
    Function functionsChain = Function.identity();

    for (Function function : functions) {
        functionsChain = functionsChain.andThen(function);
    }

    return (R) functionsChain.apply(src);
}
```

---

Otherwise, the only other I see is to use the same pattern as `Optional` or `Stream` like suggested in the comments

```java
List<Integer> fileInputStreams = converter.convertBy(fn1)
        .convertBy(fn2)
        .convertBy(fn3)
        .get();

// with this implementation

public static class InputConverter<T> {
    private final T src;

    public InputConverter(T src) {
        this.src = src;
    }

    public <R> InputConverter<R> convertBy(Function<T, R> function) {
        return new InputConverter<>(function.apply(src));
    }

    public T get() {
        return src;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve without the use of raw types?

Comment: I found a very similar answer before posting this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44521687/10430194

The solution is very elegant. Unfortunately this only works when the return types are consistent.

Comment: @Bart I have added maybe a solution that could be suitable, I'm not sure it is possible to do it full generics here, as the types to infer are dynamic, and Java is not the perfect language for this kind of flexibility

Comment: That's a very thorough answer, my friend. I combined your answer with a functional approach and I'm returning something like this `return (R) Arrays.stream(functions).reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen).apply(src);`. I'm marking yours as the best answer. Thank you!